# Show that the dot product of two basis vectors in special relativity gives the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, vectors

I'm reading Schutz's *Introduction to GR* and came across an exercise problem. The problem is the following:

> Show that the vectors $\{\vec e_{\bar \alpha }\}$ obtained from
> $$\vec e_{\bar \beta } = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\bar \beta}(-v) \, \vec e_{\alpha}$$
> satisfy $\vec e_{\bar \beta} \cdot \vec e_\bar \alpha = \eta_{\bar \alpha \bar \beta}$ for all $\bar \alpha , \bar \beta$.

At this point in the book (at the end of chapter 2) we know the following:

1. If $\vec A$ is a vector, its components transform as
   $$A^\bar \beta = \Lambda ^\bar \beta _{\alpha}(v) \, A^\alpha.$$
2. If $\{\vec e_{\bar \beta}\}$ is basis vectors in a frame $\bar O$ and $\{\vec e_{\beta}\}$ in a frame $O$,
   $$\vec e_{\bar \beta} = \Lambda ^\nu_{\bar \beta}(-v) \, \vec e_{\nu}.$$
3. If $\vec e_{\alpha}, \vec e_{\beta}$ two vectors in a frame $O$
   $$ \vec e_{\alpha} \cdot \vec e_{\beta} = \eta_{\alpha \beta}$$

How can I prove the statement in the question? I guess the question wants to ask that given in a frame $\vec e_{\alpha} \cdot \vec e_{\beta} = \eta_{\alpha\beta}$ holds shot that it also holds in any other frame with the transformations we have.

Comment: The approach is simply to compute the dot products explicitly. Another argument is that the matrices $\Lambda$ are defined to be the matrices that preserve the metric components $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^\bar\mu=\Lambda^\bar\mu_{\;\rho}x^\rho$ and $x_\bar\mu=g_{\bar\mu\bar\alpha}x^\bar\alpha=g_{\bar\mu\bar\alpha}\Lambda^\bar\alpha_{\;\sigma}x^\sigma$. Then taking the dot product:
$$\begin{align}
x^\bar\mu x_\bar\mu=&(\Lambda^\bar\mu_{\;\rho}x^\rho )g_{\bar\mu\bar\alpha}\Lambda^\bar\alpha_{\;\sigma}x^\sigma\\
=& g_{\bar\mu\bar\alpha}\Lambda^\bar\mu_{\;\rho}\Lambda^\bar\alpha_{\;\sigma}x^\rho x^\sigma.
\end{align}
$$
However, we know that the Lorentz transformation preserves the Minkowski metric, i.e.
$$g_{\bar\mu\alpha}\Lambda^\bar\mu_{\;\rho}\Lambda^\bar\alpha_{\;\sigma}=g_{\rho\sigma}.$$ so that$$x^\bar\mu x_\bar\mu=g_{\rho\sigma}x^\rho x^\sigma.$$
It is very easy to see the result if one assumes the calculation for basis vectors instead of any general four vector. So that if we have $x^\bar\mu=e_\bar\mu$ and $x_\bar\mu=\omega^\bar\mu$, where $e_\alpha$ and $\omega_\beta$ are the basis vectors and one-forms respectively we have:
$$x^\bar\mu x_\bar\mu=g_{\rho\sigma}\omega^\rho\omega^\sigma  e_\rho e_\sigma=g_{\rho\sigma}\delta^\rho_{\;\sigma}\delta^\sigma_{\;\rho}=g_{\rho\sigma}.$$